# OnItemSelected not working for custom spinner where values are from SQLite database

Tags: android

I'm new to Android studio and I'm working on a project which needs a spinner that has values populated from SQLite. I need to change an image(icon) according to the selection done by the user from the spinner.

I've tried making android:clickable="false" for the TextView on the custom layout. But it does not solve. I've also used spinner.setOnTouchListener to update the list whenever user touches the spinner.

categoryspinner_layout.xml (custom layout)

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Spinner Layout. (Has multiple spinners but without custom layout)

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewTransfers">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filterDateStart"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addFilterDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="ADD DATE"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/filterDateStart"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filterMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Recurring"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mop_viewTransfer" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewTranfers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="View Transfer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.477"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recurring_viewTransfer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/deleteCatID"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter an ID"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewTranfers" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delTransfer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="106dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="106dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="73dp"
        android:text="DELETE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/deleteCatID"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewTranfers" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/mop_viewTransfer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/recurring_viewTransfer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/filterMode" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Mode of payment"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amount_filter" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount_filter"
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/currency_filter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addFilterDate" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/currency_filter"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/amount_filter"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addFilterDate" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/filterCategory"
            android:layout_width="299dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/imageview1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

OnItemSelected

```
 package com.example.watch;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ViewTransfers extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    EditText deleteIDs, amount;
    TextView startDate;
    Button view, delete , addDate;
    Spinner mop_ViewTransfer,recurring_ViewTransfer,currency,category;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    DataHelper cDb;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_transfers);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        deleteIDs=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.deleteCatID);
        category =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.filterCategory);
        startDate =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.filterDateStart);
        amount=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_filter);
        currency=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.currency_filter);
        recurring_ViewTransfer=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.recurring_viewTransfer);
        mop_ViewTransfer=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mop_viewTransfer);
        view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewTranfers);
        delete=(Button) findViewById(R.id.delTransfer);
        addDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addFilterDate);

        implementValue();

        addDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment datePicker=new DatePickerFrangment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"date picker");
            }
        });



        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String categoryS , startDateS, recurrentS, modeS,amountS,currencyS;
                categoryS = category.getSelectedItem().toString();
                startDateS= startDate.getText().toString();
                amountS=amount.getText().toString();
                currencyS=currency.getSelectedItem().toString();
                modeS= mop_ViewTransfer.getSelectedItem().toString();
                recurrentS= recurring_ViewTransfer.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (amountS.length()!=0) amountS = amountS+" "+currencyS;

                Cursor res = myDb.getFilteredData( categoryS , startDateS,amountS, modeS,recurrentS);
                if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                    showMessage("Error", "No records found!");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (res.moveToNext()) {
                    buffer.append("ID : " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Category : " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Date : " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Amount : " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Payment : " + res.getString(4) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Recurring : " + res.getString(5) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Comments : " + res.getString(6) + "\n \n");

                }
                showMessage("Money Tracker", buffer.toString());

            }
        });

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String text =deleteIDs.getText().toString();
                if (text.length() != 0) {
                    Integer IDs = Integer.parseInt(text) ;
                    boolean check = myDb.deleteTransfer(IDs);
                    if (check == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewTransfers.this, "Data deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ViewTransfers.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewTransfers.this,"Enter a valid ID!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
    public void showMessage(String title, String Message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
        String currentDateString= DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(c.getTime());
        startDate.setText(currentDateString); }

    public void implementValue(){
        Spinner recurring_ViewTransfer = findViewById(R.id.recurring_viewTransfer);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.transaction, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        recurring_ViewTransfer.setAdapter(adapter);
        recurring_ViewTransfer.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner mop_ViewTransfer = findViewById(R.id.mop_viewTransfer);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.mop, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mop_ViewTransfer.setAdapter(adapter2);
        mop_ViewTransfer.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        Spinner currency = findViewById(R.id.currency_filter);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.currency, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        currency.setAdapter(adapter3);
        currency.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        categoryspin();
     /*   category.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                categoryspin();

                return false;
            }
        });
*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       switch (parent.getId()) {
           case R.id.filterCategory : {
               String category1 = category.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Toast.makeText(ViewTransfers.this, category1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               /*String category1 = category.getSelectedItem().toString();
               String img = cDb.getIcon(category1);

               imgIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

               int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(img, "drawable", getPackageName());
               imgIcon.setImageResource(resID);*/
           }
       }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    public  void categoryspin(){

        cDb = new DataHelper(this);
        ArrayList<String> list = cDb.getAllCategories();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.categoryspinner_layout, R.id.category, list);
        category.setAdapter(adapter3);
    }


}



There ain't any error message. When  I open the page it gave me a toast message of the 1st entry in the spinner. After that nothing happens when I click on it.
```

Comment: Add more information, code of activity or fragment

Comment: @ Anant Shah.. I've added the entire code of the activity and xml.

Comment: check the answer

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks for taking the pain to read through the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code, You have to code like this according to your current code, You have implemented event on activity context. and You have not written code for the event listener.

```
public  void categoryspin(){

    cDb = new DataHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> list = cDb.getAllCategories();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.categoryspinner_layout, R.id.category, list);
    category.setAdapter(adapter3);

     /*Add this line and it will start working with your existing code to handle spinner onItemSelected 
       event, Happy coding...*/
    category.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Note: try to use the proper naming convention, It will help you to identify/review code easily and solve bugs.

Also, this issue is not for values you are getting from the SQLite database.

Comment: Worked perfectly!. Thanks mate .. Yeah ..have to improve on my naming convention :D

Comment: @AntoThomas Accept as answer